# angular httpclient observables not unsubscribing automatically

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, angular-httpclient

I am performing a http call and subscribing to it.
If I close that component, the subscription is not destroyed, and it runs once.
Shouldn't the http subscriptions be removed automatically once I destroy a component?

Here's the method that is being called

```
getCubes() {
    this.loading_cubes = true;
    this.urlService.getCubes().subscribe({
      next:(data:any) => {
        if (data.success) {
          this.cubesDataArray = data.data[0].response;
        } else {
          Swal.fire(data.status_message);
          console.log(data.error_message);
        }
        this.loading_cubes = false;
      },
      error:(err:any) => {
        console.log(err);
        Swal.fire('Opps an error occured');
        this.loading_cubes = false;
      }
    });
  }
```

And here's the service function that's returning the http observable.

```
 getCubes() {
    return this.http.get(this.serviceURL + '/cubes', this.options);
  }
```

This is just an single case, It's happening with every req I make.
The pop ups keep coming up even after I closed the component.

Also it it possible that it is some setting in the tsconfig.json?

Comment: Is there a TypeScript error that is occurring on build? If not, it has nothing to do with TypeScript or tsconfig.json... AFAIK, you need to create a property to capture the subscription (which is returned from `subscribe` and unsubscribe from it in `ngOnDestroy`.

Comment: Little bit of googling will lead you to this article - [6 Ways to Unsubscribe from Observables in Angular](https://blog.bitsrc.io/6-ways-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-in-angular-ab912819a78f)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to hook into the onDestroy to remove your subscription:

```typescript
export MyComponent extends OnDestroy {
    mySubscription = null
    ...

    getCubes() {
        this.mySubscription = this.urlService.getCubes().subscribe({
            ...
        });
    }
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.mySubscription.unsubscribe();
    }   
}
```

Comment: This is the solution that I am using thanks for that. But shouldn't the angular http observable be destroyed by default on destroying a compontent?

Comment: That's not how they've built it unfortunately though I agree it's not as intuitive. If this is the solution you're using though can you accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Matthew provided you already good answer. There are also other options besides his anwer.

1. You can instruct RxJS to take only one result. Then code should be like:

   this.urlService.getCubes().pipe(take(1)).subscribe({
   ...
   });

This `pipe(take(1))` is instructing to only take one result.

2. Second approach would be to convert observable to promise. This can be achieved with `firstValueFrom` function from RxJS. Then code should be like:

   firstValueFrom(this.urlService.getCubes()).then({
   ...
   });

You may ask why HttpClient is behaving in this strange manner. Let me try to explain it a little bit.

HttpClient methods like get, put, post, delete etc. are returning so called `cold observables`. The main idea of them is that they are not being executed if there is now consumer on the end. You can check what will happen if you don't do subscribe - nothing will happen, request will not be sent.

This allows you also to create one "halted request" and call it mutliple times - for example with multiple subscribe.

What would need that? Let's consider this code:

```
this.urlService.getCubes()
  .pipe(retry(3))
  .subscribe({
    ...
  });
```

Here I have used `retry` operator. What it does is catching error and redoing request. In my example it will do it three times until it will pass error. Of course if first or second execution returns response then it won't be retried.

This behaviour is possible because HttpClient is returning `cold observables`. It also leads to your problem and need to do any of this solutions.

This also allows to use `cancelation token` mechanism but this is for later question to tell.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution won't work, if the component is destroyed it will still execute and that's the problem they are experiencing. The solution I provided will cancel the http request and won't execute the subscribe.

Comment: @MathewBerg, ok you are right. The problem was not clearly enough described. The problem there was he is destroying component and result from backend arrives (I didn't understand it firstly). In this situation `take(1)` or `firstValueFrom` won't be enough. 
In that situation yours solution will work the best. `takeUntil` will require another stream, automagic solutions will make code less readable. 
Only thing worth to point there is that yours solution and mine propositions should be used when required - if no side effects then mine is good enough. If side effects only yours. 
Cheers